# Chrome OS on non chrome hardware

Tags: chrome, chrome-os

I want to see how it is to hi a on `Chrome OS` for a week, so how can I install a fairly up to date Chrome system on my hardware? I know it may not be supported, so is there projects that work like it with similar `UI`? Also what kernel is Chrome running on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Chromium OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os)! It's an open-source `Gentoo Linux` derivative and `Chrome OS`s base.

The kernel for both `Chrome OS` and `Chromium OS` is `Linux`.

> Chromium OS uses the Linux Kernel. Historically we stayed on a 2.6.32 Ubuntu-based for the first several releases, but have since then moved on to track the upstream mainline kernel directly, applying our changes for the features and stability we need on top of it.

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/chromium-os-kernel

So it looks like they're using `Linux 3.13`.

Comment: But what version?? 3.10 I knew it was Linux sorry I worded it wrong

Comment: Okay thanks :) but can I auto update the system like chrome OS does